# How to programatically fix a view to a tab bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

I have a tableView inside a navigationController inside a tabBarController.
I want to programatically fix a view above the tabbar like this:

[image].

I have experimented with adding constraints without success, also because I don't know whether to use `self.view` or `self.bottomLayoutGuide` of `self.tableView` or `self.navigationController` or `self.tabBarController.tabBar` or ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 99, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 88/255, blue: 171/255, alpha: 1)
button.tintColor = .white
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
button.setTitle("YOUR TEXT", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourAction), for: .touchUpInside)

self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(button)
```

In my example, it is a `UIButton` but it can be a `UIView` too

Same example with `UIView`

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 99, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 88/255, blue: 171/255, alpha: 1)

self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: This places the view over my navigation bar.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot because this works great for me.

Comment: Oh I see it's because you define the position when creating the view. I'm using an already created view and was hoping to just add a constraint to it.

Comment: But this code works just fine. It adds the view right above the tabBar

Comment: I manually added the frame (myView.frame = ...) and now it works indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

then you will see the tableviewcell covered by navigationbar and
if you want navigationbar to be full transparency

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage:[UIImage new];
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this Swift 3.0**

Bottom view code here.

```
    let bottomview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height-63,width:self.view.frame.width, height: 80))
    bottomview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(bottomview)
```

Table view code here...

```
    let table: UITableViewController = MyTableViewController()
    let tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 500)
    tableView.dataSource = table
    tableView.delegate = table

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Comment: This places the view right below my navigation bar.